# Having multiple Meteor collections for same underlying collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

How can I create multiple Meteor collections which have the same underlying MongoDB collection? So multiple collections with same name? I would like those collections to have different `transform` and `allow` and `deny` parameters.

Comment: I explained all this, and more, at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880927/586086

Comment: @AndrewMao do you? I see how you describe how to subscribe to serveral different publications, but they end up in the same collection on the client, which is not what is desired here, I think.

Comment: `transform` is defined on the client, so you can certainly do that with different collections. `allow` and `deny` are defined on the server, so it would not be possible, unless you opened multiple mongo connections.

Answer (score 0):

see the thread at the google discussion group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/EYKiEii4veA

Comment: This will fail because you are calling `Meteor.Collection` with same name twice.