# MongoDB data not appearing in Meteor template

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I started my first app with Meteor and everything was going fine, until I noticed that a collection is no longer showing in a template.

This is my code:

**App.js**

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
        return Tasks.find();
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Meteor.subscribe("tasks");

Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
        return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
});
}
```

**App.html**

```
<template name="home">

    <h3>Open Tasks</h3>

          <ul>
            {{#each tasks}}
                {{> displayTasks}}
            {{/each}}
          </ul>

</template>

<template name="displayTasks">

    <li>{{text}}</li>

</template>
```

**Routes.js**

```
Router.route("/", function () {
    this.render("Home");
});
```

I've double-checked with http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/publish-subscribe/ and [MeteorJS template not showing data, not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595993/meteorjs-template-not-showing-data-not-appearing) and it *seems* that I've done everything correctly. I also tried changing the names and trying to display the tasks on different templates, but to no avail. MongoDB does have data and I can manually insert entries (using the Mongo console) that have their `text` fields filled out.

What else can I do to troubleshoot? Backtracing my steps hasn't helped and I'd rather avoid starting a new app from scratch.

NOTE: I'm using Iron Router.

Comment: `Template.home.helpers` instead of `Template.body.helpers`. Also you can check if the docs are published by opening your browser console and typing `Tasks.find().count()`.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it completely, thanks @David. I can't believe I missed something that important, should have RTFM properly. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, child templates don't have access to their parent's helpers. In the code above, the `tasks` helper has been defined for the `body` template, but it's needed in the `home` template. Try this instead:

```
Template.home.helpers({
  tasks: function () {
    return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  }
});
```

Note that you *can* explicitly pass a helper from a parent to a child, as seen in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122176/meteor-access-reactive-dict-variable-in-child-template), but that's uncommon.